# Fallbacks for potentially "falsy" inputs. How do I do them when handling JSONs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Suppose, I don't know for sure if there are checked `authorities` or not (but if they are present, I want them). If checked `authorities` are absent, I want jQuery to select `authorities` with no regard whether they are checked or not (in practice, it would mean retrieving the value of a hidden input). My idea of using JS's "truthy"/"falsy" concept for handling this kind of situations was this:

```js
    let user = {
        id: $(this).find('[name=id]').val(),
        username: $(this).find('[name=username]').val(),
        password: $(this).find('[name=password]').val(),
        name: $(this).find('[name=name]').val(),
        lastName: $(this).find('[name=lastName]').val(),
        department: $(this).find('[name=department]').val(),
        salary: $(this).find('[name=salary]').val(),
        age: $(this).find('[name=age]').val(),
        email: $(this).find('[name=email]').val(),
        enabledByte: $(this).find('[name=enabledByte]').val(),
        authorities: JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val()) || 
                    JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]').val())
    };
```

However, it doesn't work. Funnily enough, it *does* work in the code snippet below. Isn't `undefined`, returned by `val()` in case of a failed match, *falsy*? Go figure! My best guess is that `JSON.parse()` throws an error when parsing an `undefined` instead of returning some falsy value, as I want it to. The method doesn't accept "param OR param", does it?

**How do you think I should provide that kind of fallbacks in my case** (other than, of course, checking the falsiness of checked `authorities` separately which would be a bit too verbose for my liking)?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#users-table">All Users</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
            <div class="row tab-content">
            <div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                                <td>john_d@gmail.com</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                                <td>jane_d@gmail.com</td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
           <div id="add-new-user" class="tab-pane container">
              <h3>Fill in the forms</h3>
                              <form>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="name">Name: </label>
                                      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="last-name">Last name: </label>
                                      <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="department">Department: </label>
                                      <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
                                          <option value="IT">IT</option>
                                          <option value="HR">HR</option>
                                          <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="email">Email: </label>
                                      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" />
                                  </div>

                                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" value="Submit" />
                              </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').on('submit', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('tbody').append(
    `<tr>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=last-name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=department]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=email]').val() || 'N/A'}
         </td>
     </tr>`
    );
            const submitButton = $(this).find('[type=submit]');
            const form = $(this);

            submitButton.removeClass('btn-primary')
                .addClass('btn-success')
                .attr('value', 'User added!')
                .attr('type', 'button')
                .click(() => $('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show'));

            setTimeout(function () {
                submitButton.removeClass('btn-success')
                    .addClass('btn-primary')
                    .attr('value', 'Submit')
                    .attr('type', 'submit')
                    .off('click');
                form.trigger('reset');
            }, 8000);
});
});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options depending on your use case:

1. You can combine the `JSON.parse`s like this. This will make it fall back to the other string before it parses, so it won't error if the first value is `undefined`. However, if both values are `undefined` or one is invalid JSON, this will error.

```js
JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val()) || $(this).find('[name=authorities]').val());
```

2. If you know that the values will either be valid JSON or `undefined`, you can fall back to `null`. `null` is a valid JSON value and can be parsed. However, this will still error if either value is invalid JSON.

```js
JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val()) || $(this).find('[name=authorities]').val() || null);
```

3. If there's a chance that either value will be invalid JSON, you can surround it in a try/catch block. This way, even if it is invalid, it will not throw. This is the safest option and will never error.

```js
// Helper to make it easier to do this inline
function safeJsonParse(string) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(string);
  } catch {
    // JSON is invalid. Will implicitly return undefined.
  }
}

safeJsonParse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val()) || safeJsonParse($(this).find('[name=authorities]').val())
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.val()` returns `undefined` if the selector doesn't find any matches, and `JSON.parse(undefined)` raises an exception.

Do the fallback inside the argument list of `JSON.parse()`, so you'll parse whichever value you fetch successfully.

```
authorities: JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val() || 
                        $(this).find('[name=authorities]:first').val())
```